# display list doesn't work the proper way

Tags: c++, list, opengl

I had already coded the display list.. and when i opened it again the next day -> gone..
niiice i thought.. i've wasted hours for nothing
and the next problem is.. i can't get it to work anymore
the display list actually works but not how it should.. textures are stretched somehow

i get my world from a text file.. each platform defined by start amount of x.. end amount of x
the y amount of the platform's bottom.. u and v (which i don't use) and filter for choosing texture.
setupworld is the function that reads from the text file and writes my variables into a structure.
Oh and numblocks is the number of platforms to display

```
void setupworld(){
float xstart,xend,ystart,u,v;
unsigned int filter;
FILE *filein;
char oneline[255];
filein=fopen("data/world.txt","rt");

readstr(filein,oneline);
sscanf(oneline, "Anzahl %d\n",&numblocks);

for (int loop=0;loop<numblocks; loop++)
{
        readstr(filein,oneline);
        sscanf(oneline,"%f %f %f %f %f %d",&xstart,&xend,&ystart,&u,&v,&filter);
        block.data[loop].xstart=xstart;
        block.data[loop].xend=xend;
        block.data[loop].ystart=ystart;
        block.data[loop].u=u;
        block.data[loop].v=v;
        block.data[loop].filter=filter;
}
fclose(filein);
return;}
```

---

BuildLists() creates my Display List, but first loads the png files and the world, cause they influence my display list... i had to rewrite this part of code and i just dont know where i made the mistake..
first loop is for creating the platforms and the 2nd one for blocks.. each platform consists of a number of 2x2 blocks simply next to eachother

```
GLvoid BuildLists(){

texture[0]=LoadPNG("data/rock_gnd.png");
texture[1]=LoadPNG("data/rock_wall2.png");
texture[2]=LoadPNG("data/pilz_test.png");
setupworld();
quad[0]=glGenLists(numblocks);

for(int loop=0;loop<numblocks;loop++)
{
    GLfloat xstart,xend,ystart,u,v;
    xstart=block.data[loop].xstart;
    xend=block.data[loop].xend;
    ystart=block.data[loop].ystart;
    u=block.data[loop].u;
    v=block.data[loop].v;
    GLuint filter=block.data[loop].filter;
    GLfloat blocks=(xend-xstart)/2.0f;

    glNewList(quad[loop],GL_COMPILE);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[filter]);

        for(int y=0;y<blocks;y++)
        {
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glTexCoord2f(0.0f,0.0f);
                glVertex3f(xstart,ystart,-1.0f);
                glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f);
                glVertex3f(xstart+((y+1)*2.0f),ystart,-1.0f);
                glTexCoord2f(1.0f,1.0f);
                glVertex3f(xstart+((y+1)*2.0f),ystart+2.0f,-1.0f);
                glTexCoord2f(0.0f,1.0f);
                glVertex3f(xstart,ystart+2.0f,-1.0f);
            glEnd();                                
        }

    glEndList();
    quad[loop+1]=quad[loop]+1;
}
}
```

---

the display list is compiled during initialisation just before enabling the 2d textures
this is how i call it during my actual code

```
int DrawWorld(GLvoid){
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);         

GLfloat camtrans=-xpos;
glTranslatef(camtrans,0,0);

glPushMatrix();

for(int i=0;i<numblocks;i++)
{

    glCallList(quad[i]);
}
glPopMatrix();
return TRUE;    }
```

so this is it.. i think the mistake is in the BuildLists() function but i'm not sure anymore..

Here is the link to my screenshot.. as u see the textures look weird for some reason
http://www.grenzlandzocker.de/test.png

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot? The code looks fine at first glance, but an image can be worth a thousand words. Also, may I ask you, why you're using display lists at all? They're deprecated since OpenGL-3 and should not be used in new code. Use Vertex Buffer Objects instead.

Comment: What number numblocks holds? Maybe you broke the limits.

Comment: Use glGetError after every opengl call and see if all are passing correctly.

Comment: i'm really sry.. i just couldn't upload the screenshot.. didn't have the webspace account in mind.. why i use display lists? i actually never tried to use vbo's.. would be worth a check.. but i would prefer display lists for this project since it's my first little game :)

Comment: oh and numblocks is defined in the txt file.. it's only about 7 for now.. and the blocks are displayed.. only the texture doesn't work the proper way

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
quad[0]=glGenLists(numblocks);
```

creates numblocks display lists, but you only get the first display list id, and it is stored in quad[0]. Later, you use:

```
glNewList(quad[loop],GL_COMPILE);
```

where quad[loop] is undefined for loop != 0. You can instead use:

```
glNewList(quad[0] + loop,GL_COMPILE);
```

Because the ids for display lists are contiguous, starting with the value of quad[0]. You also need to modify your rendering code to:

```
glCallList(quad[0] + i);
```

For the same reason ...